# R: Using different subelements (specific rows of each column) with sapply

Tags: r, dplyr, do.call

I have a data.frame with customer ids and different combinations of three variables. My first step was to find the most common combinations which is achieved through the following code.

```
possible_s = c("a","b","c","d","e")
n = 10000
df = tibble(customer_id = sample(1:10000,n,replace = T ),
                s1 = sample(possible_s,n,replace = T ),
                s2 = sample(possible_s,n,replace = T ),
                s3 = sample(possible_s,n,replace = T ))


combinations = table(apply(df[,2:4], 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ""))) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  arrange(desc(n))

combinations = combinations %>% 
  mutate(
    s1 = sapply(combinations[ ,1],function(x) substr(x,1,1)),
    s2 = sapply(combinations[ ,1],function(x) substr(x,2,2)),
    s3 = sapply(combinations[ ,1],function(x) substr(x,3,3))
  )
```

Now I have want to output the ids for the most 20 most common combinations. This is a solution to do it manually for the first combination:

```
combinations[1, ]
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Var1      n s1    s2    s3   
  <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 cde     503 c     d     e 

df %>%
  mutate(count_c = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x, 'c')) )) %>% 
  mutate(count_d = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x, 'd')) )) %>% 
  mutate(count_e = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x, 'e')) )) %>% 
  filter(count_c == 1,count_d == 1,count_e == 1) %>% 
  distinct(customer_id)
```

My attempt to do it for the first 20 combinations is the following:

```
sapply( as.data.frame ( t( combinations[1:20,3:5]),stringsAsFactors = F )  ,function(y) 
  df %>%
    mutate(vfg1 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x,y[1])) )) %>% 
    mutate(vfg2 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x,y[2])) )) %>%
    mutate(vfg3 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x,y[3])) )) 
) %>%
  filter(vfg1 == 1,vfg2 == 1,vfg3 == 1) %>% 
  distinct(VERSICHERTER_BP_ID)
```

Unfortunately this does not give me the intended result. To bind the different ids together I thought of something like this:

```
do.call("bind",sapply( as.data.frame ( t( combinations[1:10,3:5]),stringsAsFactors = F )  ,function(y) 
  df %>%
    mutate(vfg1 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x,y[1])) )) %>% 
    mutate(vfg2 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x,y[2])) )) %>%
    mutate(vfg3 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x,y[3])) )) 
) %>%
  filter(vfg1 == 1,vfg2 == 1,vfg3 == 1) %>% 
  distinct(VERSICHERTER_BP_ID))
```

Besides saving all ids of the 20 first combinations in one tibble, I also want to save the ids of each combination in a list, where each combination and the corresponding ids is one element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be the most efficient way to do this. This is a solution that works:

```
top20_combinations = combinations %>% slice(1:20) %>% select(3:5)
customer_ids = vector("list", length = nrow(top20_combinations))
for (i in 1:nrow(top20_combinations)) {
  df2 = df %>%
    mutate(vfg1 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x, top20_combinations[[i,1]] )) )) %>% 
    mutate(vfg2 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x, top20_combinations[[i,2]] )) )) %>%
    mutate(vfg3 = rowSums(apply(df,2,function(x) str_count(x, top20_combinations[[i,3]] )) )) %>%
    filter(vfg1 == 1,vfg2 == 1,vfg3 == 1) %>% 
    distinct(customer_id )
   customer_ids[[i]] = df2$customer_id
}
```